# Is there any good way to encrypt my ms access database?

Tags: encryption, microsoft-access

After installing my desktop application any body can see the database on their local systems.
Even if I set Password security on access database its not going to work.Encryprion may be one
of the good technique of accomplishing this task ,i think...Please suggest....

Comment: Sounds like a question for [Super User](http://superuser.com/), not here.

Comment: What do you mean by "is not going to work". Is your db readable even if you set an access password on it?

Comment: Access passwords can be recovered easily ......

Comment: Access database passwords are not nearly as easily recovered in A2007 and A2010 as they used to be, because A2007 greatly increased the encryption level (and how it was stored). That said, database passwords are basically "security theater" not real security. If you need actual data security, you shouldn't be using a file-based datastore, but a server database engine like SQL Server or MySQL instead.

Comment: What is your goal? Keeping out the curious, controlling access to your application or actually protecting your data?

Comment: If you install SQL Server on your desktop, don't you still have access to the .mdf file?

Answer (score 1):

Since an .mdb is simply a file, you could use third-party software (such as the free and excellent TrueCrypt) to encrypt the file itself.

Comment: To what end? How would this protect it?

Comment: It would protect it from an unauthorized user who has access to the mdb, five minutes of free time, and an internet connection to download an MS Access password cracker/recovery utility.

Answer (score 0):

For Access 2007, if you use the ACCDB database format and password protect your DB, which will automatically encrypt it. I don't know about older versions of Access, but see [this tutorial](http://databases.about.com/od/tutorials/ss/passwordprotect.htm) for Access 2007.

Comment: I am working wiht .mdb format..thats why i asked this question..

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a really old thread, but other may come across it.
While Access 2003 security would allow user groups etc to be set up, as mentioned above, it could still be hacked.
Perhaps a better method would be to get your IT to set up a folder where only your user login had access to it, thereby preventing other users on the network from getting into the folder and seeing he files.